# filenotfoundexception when referencing filepath

Tags: java, audio, libgdx, filepath

I am trying to develop a game where it uses a song. The song plays as background music.

I am trying to analyse the current frequency of the audio spectrum and output its value. I have used the FFT algorithm to get the frequency, but now I need to get the length of the song. So I am utilising this code:

```
FileHandle filemain = Gdx.files.internal("data/determination.mp3");
        File file = new File(filemain.toString());
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        long audioFileLength = file.length();
        int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
        float frameRate = format.getFrameRate();
        float durationInSeconds = (audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate));
```

But then it returns a `FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION`. using the `Gdx.files.internal("data/determination.mp3");` it works fine. but I can't use that in the `AudioInputSream` declaration as it takes a file, not a file handle. And if I use the file path in the `AudioInputStream` like I have above, it returns the error.

Where am I going wrong? and how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not looking in a place where that file is.

Comment: Hint: Print out filemain.toString().  Is that a valid file path, and one that leads the file you want, within the context of the current directory, etc?  (I'm guessing that maybe your Gdx files are in some sort of zip-like container that can't be addressed with a normal File open operation.)

Comment: It is printing out the right file path, where it is places exactly. So why would it be available to the GDX but not the File operation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at the Java 7 API for a File object, specifically the section on constructors, it looks as though this object needs to be constructed with a String that gives the correct filepath to the file or a URI.

Check out this link to all the available overloaded constructors for a File here: [docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#constructor_summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#constructor_summary)

Try this: Give the mp3 file location as a String object to the File object's constructor just as you did for the FileHandle object constructor. Or, place the .mp3 somewhere else on the file system and try to call it with an absolute path.

If this does not work consult this documentation on the various ways to read from files and create FileHandle objects in the game engine: [Different ways to construct FileHandle objects](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileModule)

This also has a bunch of information on the FileHandle object API:[FileHandle API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html)

Good luck with your video game.  I want to try the game engine you are using for your game someday. Either this one or the jMonkey3D game engine. :D

Comment: I know it won't take the **FileHandle** object reference, but when I try reference the file without the file handle, it gives me a filenotfoundexcetion

Comment: I edited my answer taking this information into account.  Let me know if it works plox. :D

Comment: That gives me the FileNotFoundException error which is why I posted the question. Seems that there is no ways around this :(

Comment: Hmm :/ I guess it is not finding the file.  Are you sure you are typing the path to the file correctly?

Comment: Copy paste the exact code and file path, even changed to other files, if I don't use the FileHandle, it spews out the error

Comment: Massive bummer. You are importing the java.io.File package?

Comment: Can you put the .mp3 in some other directory and see if the compiler or JRE  can find it? You could leave the FileHandle as is but do this for the File object. I do not think it would matter since both objects are calling the same thing just in different places on the file system. Maybe the File object cannot see inside the game engine's code for some reason.

Comment: It seems that the engine doesn't like referencing the files without the file handle

Comment: `FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.absolute("/some_dir/subdir/myfile.txt");`  try this

Comment: `Gdx.files.internal("data/determination.mp3").read()` that returns an Input Stream, which is what I need! haha found it. but now it does not support mp3 files.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileModule this page has lots of variations on calling resource files like .mp3s or .txts files for a game.  You could try `FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.external("myfile.txt");` or `FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.classpath("myfile.txt");`